# Random default value for integer in database for each instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I'm using this system for voting content in my rails app: https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system

Is there a way to make the default score for any votable item some random number for each instance.

If I store something like rand(5..12) it will only pick a random default value one time, how do I get a random default value for every different row or field?

```
      create_table "rs_evaluations", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "reputation_name"
t.integer  "source_id"
t.string   "source_type"
t.integer  "target_id"
t.string   "target_type"
t.float    "value",           :default => 0.0
t.datetime "created_at",                       :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",                       :null => false
```

end

Comment: Simply add a before_create then specify the default value by rand or something. No way to add rand options within migration.

Comment: Since version 3.0 `activerecord-reputation-system` supports custom aggregation functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [before_create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) filter.

```
class RsEvaluation < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :update_value

  def update_value
    self.value = rand(5..12)
  end

end
```

However; Since [Evaluation](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/blob/master/lib/reputation_system/models/evaluation.rb) is not your own model, but one from a library, try opening the class and patching it:

```
module ReputationSystem

  class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :update_value

    def update_value
      self.value = rand(5..12)
    end
  end

end
```

This would be placed in your `config/initializers` folder.

Comment: Thanks! Where would I put this? Do I need to create a new file?

Comment: This would be your model. I'm assuming you already have a model called RsEvaluation (to match your rs_evaluations table). If not, it goes in app/models.

Comment: Didn't work, could it be because of some remaining? https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/issues/23

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that this wasn't your own model. I've updated my answer. You have two options, either monkey patch it, or sub-class it... not knowing what this gem does, it might be more straightforward to patch it.

Comment: How would I do this? Can I access the file, or do I just create my own model?

Comment: Just create your own file, call it whatever you want, and add it to the `lib` folder of your project. Rails should automatically load this, and patch the Evaluation class for you.

Comment: @KatieHeidmann possibly because in newer rails `lib` isn't load automaticallty. Try to drop in `config/initializers/something.rb`

Comment: thanks @fotanus! lol, been doing a lot of Sinatra recently, so it slipped my mind that `lib` isn't auto loaded anymore.