# Overriding model in gem, adding callback and methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, callback, rubygems

I've installed the `ActiveRecord` Reputation System on my app. How would I go about overriding or adding a callback/method to [Evaluation](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/blob/master/lib/reputation_system/models/evaluation.rb) model?

In general how do you add to any model for a gem you installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply reopen the class:

```
module ReputationSystem
  class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base
    def my_method_here
      puts "Yey!"
     end
   end
end
```

You can put this file in `config/initializers/my_monkey_patch.rb` or in `lib/my_monkey_patch.rb`, but the later must be loaded into your code.

Comment: Can you take a look at this questions, this is what I'm trying to do, I just did what you wrote, it still didn't work, perhaps my method is off? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621396/random-default-value-for-integer-in-database-for-each-instance/18621466?noredirect=1#comment27485536_18621466

Comment: @KatieHeidmann Have you restarted the server/console, right? Does console finds something if you type `ReputationSystem::Evaluation` ? If it can find, calling `ReputationSystem::Evaluation.new.my_method_here` should work...