# How to override model from the doorkeeper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, doorkeeper

Do you have any idea how to override `Doorkeeper::Application` provided by the Doorkeeper gem.Let's say I want to add validation, callbacks and so on. Db table is named `auth_applications`.

I created a model named application.rb containing the following but my before_create call is not triggered. What's the best approach?

```
module Doorkeeper
  class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ApplicationMixin

    require 'identicon'
    before_create :generate_identicon

    def generate_identicon
      self.identicon = Identicon.data_url_for name, 128, [255, 255, 255]
    end

  end
end
```

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668645/overriding-model-in-gem-adding-callback-and-methods) code should be declared as an initializer. However I'd like to have a classic model since there is a lot I want to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'm doing right now, still developing anyway so I'll update if I'll find issues.

*I'm doing this using ActiveRecord, maybe for Mongoid/Mongomapper some changes need to be done.*

Luckily [Doorkeeper::Application](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/doorkeeper/orm/active_record/application.rb) has all the configuration to set the correct table name so you don't have to bother about that.

With this in mind you can just add `app/models/application.rb` like this:

```
class Application < Doorkeeper::Application
  require 'identicon'
  before_create :generate_identicon

  def generate_identicon
    self.identicon = Identicon.data_url_for name, 128, [255, 255, 255]
  end
end
```

And you're done.

I'm using this to customize Doorkeepe::Application with RailsAdmin (just to add some keyword if someone lands here)

Comment: Thanks @enrico-carlesso I came up with the same solution late last night. Easy after all. Closing it.